# Composition $f\circ g$ not Riemann-integrable, where $f$ Riemann-integrable and $g$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, fake-proofs

Let $g:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ be continuous and $f:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Riemann-integrable.

Why is it not possible to show by means of Darboux-sums that $(f\circ g)$ is Riemann-integrable?

---

The sketch of a fake-proof could be as follows:

As $f$ is Riemann-integrable there exists a partition $P$ of $[c,d]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. Let be $\delta>0$ the width of the smallest subintervall $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ of $[c,d]$ which is obtained by the partition $P$.

Let be $P':=\{t_0,t_1,\cdots, t_n\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$ such that for all $i\in \{1, 2,\cdots,n\}$ and $x,y \in [t_{i-1},t_i]$ it follows (due to uniform continuity of $g$):
$$|g(x)-g(y)|\leq |\sup\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]- \inf\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}|<\delta.$$

Now let's define $$M_i:=\sup\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}\\m_i:=\inf\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}.$$

So I can simply construct a partition $P'':=\{d_0,d_1,\cdots d_m\}$ of $g([a,b])$ by using the finite many $M_i$'s and $m_i$'s. For example, a $d_j$ can be either  $d_j=\sup\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}$ or $d_j=\inf\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}$. It follows that for all $j\in\{1,2,\cdots,m\}$ we have $|d_{j-1}-d_j|\leq\sup\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}-\inf\{g(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}<\delta$.

So the width of every subinterval which is obtained by the partition $P'$ of $[c,d]$ is smaller than $\delta$. Hence, $U(f\circ g, P')-L(f\circ g, P')<U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$ and the composition would be Riemann-integrable.

Where are my mistakes?

Comment: $[t_i, t_{i+1}]\subset [c,d]$ and $g$ is only defined on $[a,b]$, then if $x,y\in [t_i, t_{i+1}]$  it is possible that $g(x), g(y)$ are no longer well defined

Comment: @AndrewShedlock, I only consider those subintervals $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ which lie in the image of $g$. So I don't understand your point that $g(x)$ and $g(y)$ are no longer well defined?

Comment: If $x\in [t_i, t_{i+1}]$ lie in the image of $g$, then all you know is that there is an $\alpha\in [a,b]$ such that $g(\alpha) = x$

Comment: @RRL, I have edited my question and added some clarifications. However, I still don't see where the fake-proof fails?

Comment: The ultra-short answer to the question why it isn't possible is of course that $f \circ g$ need not be Riemann-integrable. Okay, that isn't very informative. So the more informative short answer is: That $f$ is Riemann-integrable means that the total length of intervals on which the oscillation of $f$ is large is very small when the partition is fine enough. But the total length of intervals in a partition of $[a,b]$ that are mapped into such intervals by $g$ can still be large. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20063).